# Automatically Add/Remove checkboxes when list changes (Google App Script)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm making a variable list of names. In column B there are names and in column C checkboxes. I would like checkboxes to be added or removed automatically when adding or removing names in column B.
I've been testing this code, but it only put TRUE / FALSE where the checkboxes would go. But I couldn't get it to replace TRUE / FALSE values with checkboxes.
(Sry if my English isn't perfect, I'm from Argentina.)

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("NamesCheckboxes"); //change this to the name of your sheet
  ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  
  //PICK ONE & comment out the other one:
  //var names = ss.getRange("names");//Use this if you are naming the range
  var names = ss.getRange("B4:B");//Use this if you are naming the ranges
  
  var namesValues = names.getValues(); //Get array of all the names
  
  //PICK ONE & comment out the other one:
  //var checkboxes = ss.getRange("checkboxes"); //Use this if you are naming the range
  var checkboxes = ss.getRange("C4:C"); //Use this if you want to hard-code your range
  
  var cbRows = checkboxes.getHeight(); //Get # of rows in the ranges
  var cbValues = checkboxes.getValues(); //Get array of all the checkbox column cell values
  //Logger.log(cbValues);
  
  var newCBValues = new Array(cbRows); //Create an array to store all the new checkboxes values before we edit the actual spreadsheet
  
  for (var row = 0; row < cbRows; row++) {
    newCBValues[row] = new Array(0); // Make the array 2 dimensional (even though it only has 1 column, it must be 2D).
    if (namesValues[row] == "" || namesValues[row] == " ") { //If the name cell of this row is empty or blank then...
      newCBValues[row][0] = " "; //Set the value to one space (which will make the cell NOT true or false, and thus NOT display a checkbox).
      //Logger.log("newCBValues[" + row + "][0]: " + newCBValues[row][0]);
    }else{ //otherwise, if the name cell isn't blank...
      if (cbValues[row][0] === true) {
        newCBValues[row][0] = true; //Keep the checkbox checked if it's already checked
      }else{ //If the name cell isn't blank, and it's not true...
        newCBValues[row][0] = false; //Then Keep it or set it to False (an empty checkbox):
        
      }   
    }
  }
  checkboxes.setValues(newCBValues); // now that we have a completed array of our new checkbox values, let's edit the sheet with them!
  
}
```

Comment: your solution might work for now but not getting advantage of the event object will cost you a lot of performance down the road

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all the people that took the time to help me!
I've used the script for a while now, but it's too slow and sometimes it deselect your selected checkbox when you change your selection fast enough.

So I came with a nice, fast, and easy walkaround, using conditional formating. The checkboxes column that may change the length, has checkboxes for all its height, but in cells where you don't need the checkbox, it hides it with the conditional formatting, making both the background and the checkbox while.

Performance-wise is the fastest solution I've tried, and also it's the simplest one to implement.

I can't believe I didn't think about this solution earlier.

Again, thanks to everyone who came by and took the time to help me.

Answer (score 2):

### Before setting the values you need to convert the range into checkboxes

There are two ways to do it:

1.

```
checkboxes.setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireCheckbox()).setValues(newCBValues);
```

2. 

```
checkboxes.insertCheckboxes().setValues(newCBValues);
```

Comment: Thanks!!! That was the line of code I was missing!!